# Transforming date column into two columns based on a unique ID

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

So I currently have a table where I have a date in a single column and a corresponding bucket that are linked to an ID:

| ID | Bucket1 | Date1 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 2015-01-02 |
| 1 | 1 | 2016-01-02 |
| 2 | 0 | 2015-01-03 |
| 2 | 1 | 2016-01-04 |
| 2 | 2 | 2017-01-05 |
| 3 | 0 | 2016-01-06 |
| 3 | 1 | 2016-01-07 |

I am in need of transforming the table so that I am able to determine or calculate the datediff between two buckets/dates for each unique ID, ideally transforming the table to look like this:

| ID | Bucket1 | Date1 | Bucket2 | Date2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 2015-01-02 | 1 | 2016-01-02 |
| 2 | 0 | 2015-01-03 | 1 | 2016-01-04 |
| 2 | 1 | 2016-01-04 | 2 | 2017-01-05 |
| 3 | 0 | 2016-01-06 | 1 | 2016-01-07 |

Where for each bucket/date change, I am able to have in one column the date associated with the bucket before it was changed and in the other the the date that it was changed and the corresponding bucket it was changed to.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you could use a use `LEAD` within a CTE here, and then filter out the rows that have `NULL` in the derived column `Date2` (or `Bucket2`):

```sql
WITH CTE AS(
        SELECT ID,
               Bucket1,
               Date1,
               LEAD(Bucket1) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY Date1) AS Bucket2,
               LEAD(Date1) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY Date1) AS Date2
        FROM dbo.YourTable)
SELECT ID,
       Bucket1,
       Date1,
       Bucket2,
       Date2
FROM CTE
WHERE Date2 IS NOT NULL;
```

Answer (score -1):

A bit of a rudimental solution.
You could try and join the table on itself, be careful as this can create a cartesian product if not done correctly.

```
Select * 
From Table as A
Join Table as B on A.ID = B.ID
Where A.BucketID <> B.BucketID
```

Comment: This won't return the result set the OP is after. For example, you will get *6* rows for `ID` `2`.